Module "http" has been externalized for browser compatibility. Cannot access "http.METHODS" in client code
I am following a yotube tutorial on how to make a twitter clone and I understand almost everything.
However, I am encountering an error like this express.js?v=2bb3381c:1288 Module "fs" has been externalized for browser compatibility. Cannot access "fs.Stats" in client code. See https://vitejs.dev/guide/troubleshooting.html#module-externalized-for-browser-compatibility for more details. for fs, path, http. I don't understand why this happend as it said i am using backend packages in the client/browser side. But i am not. The image above is the error messages. This is my vite.config.js file
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    port: 4000,
    proxy: {
      "/api": {
        target: "http://localhost:5000",
        changeOrigin: true,
      },
    },
  },
});


I am using mern stack for this project. Please help me guys.
I tried googling the answers, searching in the docs, and ask AIs but did't work. I have a folder name twitter-clone and it has 2 folders frontend and backend. I create my vite react app inside the frontend directory but i wrote the npm init commnad in root directory. The backend directory has all the logics.

You cannot run code that requires the fs module in a browser.  It's functionality does not exist in a browser.  Probably you are using a module that itself relies on the fs module as a dependency if it's not your code that is including it directly.
